# Best estimate for a decile or quintile mean from a known distributional family?

Tags: mean, quantiles, order-statistics

Suppose you have a population drawn from a known distributional family f with a vector of unknown parameters θ. You may also assume that the distribution is strictly non-negative and skewed, with a finite mean and variance. Suppose further that you have a large sample, sorted least to greatest. The sample is then divided into n groups by n-tile (e.g. 10 groups by decile). For convenience, assume that the number of observations is divisible by n.

You use the entire sample to produce a MLE of the unknown θ. From this point, one could estimate the quantiles numerically by finding the values for which the PDF f(θhat) is equal to an integer multiple of 1/n, and then the quantile group means by integrating xf(θhat; x) between adjacent quantiles. Or, you could find the quantiles by dividing the sorted population into n groups of equal size and taking the sample quantile group means as estimates of the true quantile group means.

If my interest is in the quantile group means, rather than the quantiles themselves, is there any good reason to prefer one of these estimates over the other, in terms of bias, variance, MSE, or some other standard basis? Or does it depend on the underlying distribution, and if so, how? If anyone wants to talk about any other candidate estimator, I'd be happy to hear that as well.

Any help or pointers to literature will be greatly appreciated.